# code to find Min(date) and display current value in database

Tags: vb.net

I'm very new to vb.net.Currently doing a system where one barcode can have multiple location. What i want is I want to display the earliest location for the barcode when user enters the barcode and click checkin button..And once the user checkOut the barcode,the location to be displayed will be changed. It will take the value of the barcode which is haven't checkout yet.  I'm really stuck. Can anyone help me to settle this ?

> ```
>     Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM barscan WHERE Barcode=@barcode,CheckOut=NULL,Min(Date)"
>     Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(theQuery, con)
>     cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", TextBox1.Text)
>     Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
>         If reader.HasRows Then                reader.Read()
>             TextBox2.Text = reader("Location").ToString
>         End If
>     End Using
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT Min(Date) as MinDate FROM barscan WHERE Barcode=@barcode and CheckOut=NULL"
Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(theQuery, con)
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", TextBox1.Text)
Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
    If reader.HasRows Then                
      while reader.Read()
        TextBox2.Text = reader("MinDate").ToString
      End while
    End If
End Using
```

Comment: Hi shep..Thanks for ur respond..But I want to display location where CheckOut=Null and Min(Date) as Date.It's not working :(

Comment: Hi Misha, what does your data table look like?